# How does memory usage affect javascript performnce

Tags: javascript, performance, memory, memory-leaks

I have two question about memory usage in javascript:

1. I read a lot about memory leak, but how the memory affect the performance? Is there any damage?
2. Without memory leak, if I use memory too much, like reach some limit of the browser(does the browser have memory usage limit?), does this effect performance?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do have a Memory-limit (mostly at about 5 MB). When this limit is reached, the user gets a message, that the website requests more than x MB and asks the user if the website is allowed to do so.

memory leaks and heavy memory usage shouldn't have a too big impact on the performance, but it's always a good thing to prevent these. Try to only use what you actually need and don't create hundreds or thousands of useless objects.